# Connecting any database directly from flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3, flex4, flexbuilder

Is it possible to connect any database from flex directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not unless you use Adobe AIR for desktop at which time you'd be using the SQLLite api's to create/connect to a sqlite database file.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=SQL_01.html

Anything else is going to require a back end service to handle such transactions.

Answer (score 6):

You can use asSQL as mentioned by michael, or use the Adobe Air runtime.

However, this must be said about using this library: **It is EXTREMELY insecure to have a straight database connection from the client** unless it's from Adobe Air since the db is local.

You don't want to send your username/password over the internet to connect to a database unless you really don't care about the data or security of your data.  I would recommend you use a middleware solution, like PHP or Java that interfaces your database for your client to get the data it needs.

Answer (score 1):

You may try asSQL.

http://ntt.cc/2008/02/01/actionscript-mysql-driver-assql-access-database-from-flex.html

http://code.google.com/p/assql/source/browse/trunk/assql/asSQL_PureAS3/src/com/maclema/mysql/Connection.as