# flex not importing SQL based connections?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I'm trying to include a database un flex4 (flashbuilder) project, i don't see data and SQL packages in the import? What might be the reason? Should i add external library?

```
        import flash.data.SQLConnection;
        import flash.data.SQLStatement;
        import flash.events.SQLErrorEvent;
        import flash.events.SQLEvent;
```

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
1172: Definition flash.data:SQLConnection could not be found.   EyeVision1.mxml /EyeVision1/src line 28 Flex Problem

Comment: Is this an AIR project? I don't see it in the tags. Those classes are AIR only.

Comment: No its for flashbuilder project. Can't i use database connection in normal web based flashbuilder project?

Comment: No you can't, unless you use a web server as a gateway but you can't make a connection directly from flash to a DB server.

Comment: You can connect the database directly from flex.  You may have a look to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use those classes only in an AIR project, not in a web-based Flex project. AIR comes packaged with a [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) database to which you can connect using these classes.

A Flex web-based application runs on the client not on a server, so if you want to access a database on the server you'll have to use a server side language to do it and pass the results to the Flex app on the client side. If you want to access a local database, well... you can't (except perhaps using HTML5 local storage and [ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html)).

Comment: So if i want to just access MySql server for database in flashbuilder, Should i be using php scripting language for handling basic CRUD application? 

All i want to do is simple database which keep track of some database operation.

Comment: Indeed, php or whatever server side language you like.

Comment: thanks RIAstar, i will use php and try access to database, fingers crossed, hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect the database directly from flex but this is not recommended because of the security reason.

You may try asSQL to do so.

Have a look on the following question:

[Connecting any database directly from flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418055/connecting-any-database-directly-from-flex/5418988#5418988)